# Magento fiddle as like js fiddle

Tags: feature-request

As in Stackoverflow there is **Run Code Snipet** , we can write html, css, js code and show the result in question only.

like that there are lot of **php fiddles** also available online.

is it possible to make something like that for magento.

If this is implemented in mse , than we can show the result of code in question only instead of providing external links.

Comment: @QaisarSatti even so, I don't think we'll ever see PHP fiddles on SO anyways. But introducing snippet runners on MSE is a good idea though, it could be of help on certain occasions.

Comment: @JulienLachal totally agree on your both points ;) but how you run the magento code and test it? think no need of it

Comment: @QaisarSatti well... tbh I didn't really think this through. Having a snippet runner for pure JS won't be relevant on MSE since we're focusing on Magento. Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't see this integrated on Stackexchange for technical reasons but if you want to link to an executable example, you could use http://stargento.com

Comment: Thanks , Thats really wonderfull ,  really an amazing link,  your answer showed me that everything is possible....